# asp.net mvc Join two tables to a single list item in html unordered list

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, join, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have successfully used an sql inner join with two tables in webforms to join two tables to a single html unordered list.

I am using Asp.net MVC 5 Entityframework 6

I am trying to join the same two tables in MVC to again output a single html unordered list.

The first table is named team with the column id the second table is named teamgallery with a column teamID.  The values of team.id and teamgallery.teamID are equal.

in the controller:

```
dynamic dmodel = new ExpandoObject();
dmodel.Teamre = (from pd in db.teams
                join od in db.teamgalleries on pd.id equals od.teamID
                where pd.Catresales == "yes"
                select new 
                {
                    pd.id,
                    pd.name,
                    od.picture
                 }).ToList();
return View(dmodel);
```

In the view:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var teamre in Model.Teamre)
    {
        <li>
            @teamre
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

In the web browser this returns a list like this:

{ id = 1, name = John Doe, picture = picture1.jpg }

{ id = 2, name = Jane Doe, picture = picture2.jpg }

If I change the razor code to display just the names:

```
@teamre.name
```

I'll receive this error

Server Error in '' Application.
'object' does not contain a definition for 'name'

The error shows even if I write

```
name = pd.name,
```

Comment: Don't declare it `dynamic`, there is no reason for it here, just use `var`. Also, how is `Teamre` defined in class `ExpandoObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, adding a ViewModel for the name and picture solved the issue.

```
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dmodel = new ExpandoObject();
        dmodel.Teamre = (from pd in db.teams
                         join od in db.teamgalleries on pd.id equals od.teamID
                         where pd.Catresales == "yes"
                         select new 
                         {
                           pd.id,
                           pd.name,
                           od.picture
                         }
                         ).ToList();
```

And Razor

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var teamre in Model.Teamre)
    {
        <li>
            @teamre.name
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
@foreach (var teamre in dmodel.Teamre)
{
    <li>
        @teamre.name
    </li>
}
```

I think your using the wrong collection to iterate through...see my code change above.